# Why does adding virtual method increase class size in C++?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class a {
  virtual int foo() {
    return 0;
  }
};

class b {
  int foo() {
    return 0;
  }
};

int main() {
  cout << sizeof(b) << endl;
  cout << sizeof(a) << endl;
}
```

Output (with g++ 4.9, -O3):

```
1
8
```

I assume the increase in size is due to adding a vpointer. But I thought the compiler would see that a is not actually deriving or being derived from anything, hence there is no need to add the vpointer?

Comment: It is not marked `final`, so how could the compiler see that it is not being derived from, say in another file?

Comment: I thought the developer would see that it is not actually deriving or being derived from anything, why there is a need to add virtual keyword to class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The vpointer is needed because the compiler cannot guarantee an external (e.g. shared) library does not use a derived type. The existence-of-derived-class resolution happens at runtime.

Comment: Imagine if that file contained `int j (a& bar) { return bar.foo(); }`  -- how would the compiler make that work?

Comment: Is that a rhetorical question?

Comment: Yes. My point is the same as yours -- the compiler has no idea what code it can't see might do.

Answer (score 1):

Run-time type information.  Any polymorphic class creates extra meta-data in the program to make things like `typeof` and `dynamic_cast` work.  This is in addition to the virtual function table.